# Deriving Outline Numbering based on CONNECT BY hierarchy

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchy

I desire to create an automatically numbered outline based on a CONNECT BY query result.

IF my query results are as follows:

```
level col1
----- --------
1     text1
1     text2
2     text3
3     text4
3     text5
1     text6
```

I am interested in deriving the numeric hierarchy values like so:

```
level outline col1
----- ------- --------
1     1       text1
1     2       text2
2     2.1     text3
3     2.1.1   text4
3     2.1.2   text5
1     3       text6
```

it feels like a `sys_connect_by_path` or windowed `lag` - but I'm not seeing it...

Comment: What does your input look like? (That will save us time creating the test data, too.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't provide test data, so I will illustrate on the `scott.emp` table instead.

```
select  level,
        substr(sys_connect_by_path(rn, '.'), 2) as outline,
        empno
from    (
          select empno, mgr,
                 row_number() over (partition by mgr order by empno) as rn
          from   scott.emp
        )
start   with mgr is null
connect by mgr = prior empno
order   siblings by empno
;

LEVEL OUTLINE        EMPNO
----- -------------- -----
    1 1               7839
    2 1.1             7566
    3 1.1.1           7788
    4 1.1.1.1         7876
    3 1.1.2           7902
    4 1.1.2.1         7369
    2 1.2             7698
    3 1.2.1           7499
    3 1.2.2           7521
    3 1.2.3           7654
    3 1.2.4           7844
    3 1.2.5           7900
    2 1.3             7782
    3 1.3.1           7934
```

In the subquery, we give a sequential number to "siblings" (rows/employees that have the same direct parent), and we use that in `sys_connect_by_path`. To get the "right" ordering from the hierarchical query, you need to order siblings the same way you ordered them in the subquery (in my case, by `empno`, which is primary key; in your case, if `col1` may have duplicates, order by `col1, rowid` in both places to break ties).

Comment: This did the trick.  thanks for clearing my hurdle :)